# Twig variable not exist during submit inside ajax success function

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

I have a form that is sent in ajax in POST, I check if the form is valid in my controller and if it is valid then I replace this form by another form in my userForm div thanks to the ajax success function. When I inspect the HTML code, the first form is replaced by the second form and it has the Twig variable values ​​in the "value" of each input. So far everything is fine.

Then I want to submit the second form automatically in jquery but I have a 500 error in the Network tab :

> Variable "nom" does not exist.

I don't understand why I get this error while the content of my variable is displayed when I check the HTML code..

I tried to define the "value" of each input in JS rather than Twig variables but it doesn't work either, although I don't have a 500 error.

My main view :

```
<img src="{{ asset('loader/loader.gif', 'image_site') }}" alt="Loader" id="spinner" class="mt-30">

    <div id="userForm">
        {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'contact-form user-form'}}) }}

        {{ form_errors(form) }}

        {{ form_widget(form.nom) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.nom) }}

        {{ form_widget(form.prenom) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.prenom) }}

        {{ form_widget(form.pays) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.pays) }}

        {{ form_widget(form.tel) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.tel) }}

        {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.email) }}

        {{ form_widget(form.submit) }}

        {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>

<script>
        $(function () {
            let registerForm = "{{ path('site_devenir_vip_ajax_payment_form') }}";

            $("#spinner")
                .hide();

            $(document)
                .on("submit", "form", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: registerForm,
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: $(this)
                            .serialize(),
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $("#spinner")
                                .show();
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            if (data.code === "ok") {
                                $("#userForm").html(data.response);
                                $("#paymentForm")
                                    .submit();
                            } else {
                                console.log(data);
                            }
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                            $("#spinner")
                                .hide();
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {

                        },
                    });
                });
        });
    </script>
```

The controller :

```
/**
     * @Route("/{id<\d+>?1}/{slug}", methods={"GET", "POST"}, name="show")
     * @Security("is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')")
     */
    public function show(Request $request, Offre $offre, $slug): Response
    {
        if ($offre->getSlug() !== $slug) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('site_devenir_vip_show', [
                'id'   => $offre->getId(),
                'slug' => $offre->getSlug(),
            ], Response::HTTP_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
        }

        $utilisateur = new User();

        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $utilisateur);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $session = new Session(new NativeSessionStorage(), new AttributeBag());
        $session->set('offre', $offre->getId());

        return $this->render('site/pages/devenir_vip/show.html.twig', [
            'form'  => $form->createView(),
            'offre' => $offre,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/load-payment-form", condition="request.isXmlHttpRequest()", name="ajax_payment_form", methods={"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function paymentForm(Request $request): Response
    {
        $utilisateur = new User();

        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $utilisateur);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() === true) {
            if ($form->isValid() === true) {

                if ($request->getSession() === null) {
                    return new Response('Une erreur s\'est produite pendant la récupération de l\'offre.');
                }

                $offreSession = $request->getSession()->get('offre');
                $offre        = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Offre::class)->find($offreSession);

                $response = [
                    'code'     => 'ok',
                    'response' => $this->render('site/layout/partials/ajax/payment_form.html.twig', [
                        'nom'          => $utilisateur->getNom(),
                        'prenom'       => $utilisateur->getPrenom(),
                        'email'        => $utilisateur->getEmail(),
                        'tel'          => $utilisateur->getTel(),
                        'pays'         => $utilisateur->getPays(),
                        'accountId'    => $this->getParameter('app.payment.account_id'),
                        'abonnementId' => $offre->getAbonnementId(),
                    ])->getContent(),
                ];

                return new JsonResponse($response);
            }

            return new Response('Le formulaire comporte des erreurs.');
        }

        return $this->render('site/layout/partials/ajax/payment_form.html.twig');
    }
```

payment_form.html.twig :

```
<form method="post" action="https://mywebsite.com/" id="paymentForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="NOM" value="{{ nom }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="PRENOM" value="{{ prenom }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="EMAIL" value="{{ email }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="TEL" value="{{ tel }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="PAYS" value="{{ pays }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="{{ accountId }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="ABONNEMENT" value="{{ abonnementId }}">
</form>
```

Currently I am stuck at this line because I have a 500 error :

`$("#paymentForm").submit();`

Comment: You don't pass in the variables to your template when the form is not recognized as submitted. Maybe that code path is executed? This could happen if the post data is not correctly mapped to your form. Check the request body when submitting the form without AJAX and with to see if for example you need to add a prefix for the form name or something like that.

Comment: So you think the problem comes from my controller?

Comment: Looks like `$form->isSubmitted()` does not return `true` in the method `paymentForm`, therefore `payment_form` is rendered without any paramters (`return $this->render('site/layout/partials/ajax/payment_form.html.twig');`)

Comment: I managed to correct this 500 error but I feel that it ignores my $("#paymentForm").submit();

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want render the payment form after receive the user form ? In your controller when the user is registered you can registry the payment directly without passed it in the front.

So if you want also passed it in the front I use this in the JsonResponse:

```
$response = ['template' => $this->renderView('@your_template', ['form'=>$paymentForm])];
return new JsonResponse($response, JsonResponse::HTTP_OK);
```

Also you can surcharge the first form (user) action by passing the new url:

```
$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $utilisateur, ['action'=> 'your_url', 'method' => 'POST');
```

And in the ajax submit form you can get the form url without create let registerForm.

Question: The let registerForm have a route name site_devenir_vip_ajax_payment_form and your action in controller ajax_payment_form did you have a name prefix?

May I help you.

Comment: I am obliged because the payment platform requires that I send a form in POST with specific "name" fields. The user must be redirected to the platform URL at the same time as the POST so I can not even do a CURL.  And I have to create an idle user in my database before sending the payment form

Comment: I removed the prefix on the payment_form because I have to name the "name" of each field in upper case and exactly as I named them

Comment: Try to add a submit button to payment_form.html.twig. This action in your form is good url action="https://mywebsite.com/"?

Comment: He is already there : {{ form_widget(formKlikAndPay.submit) }}

Comment: I created a new ask here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54606896/jquery-function-submit-is-not-working-in-ajax-success-function